# Is repair of stone chips on heated windshield possible?

Tags: heat, windshield

Most windshields that get a stone chip are repaired, not replaced. I, however, have a heated windshield on my 2016 Toyota RAV4, and I got a stone chip on it recently.

The heating is implemented by many very thin vertical wires that are barely visible. They are much thinner than rear window wires, but their density (wires per inch) is much greater.

Is it possible to repair stone chips on this windshield or should the entire windshield be replaced when damaged? Specifically, I am concerned that the repair requires drilling of holes at the ends of the cracks to prevent the cracks from extending, and the drilling could damage the heating wires. Do they drill holes when repairing windshield stone chips that have small cracks?

What are the risks that the heating fails to work in the area of the stone chip after repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, repair is possible as the repair is on the outer surface. Will the heating element get damaged - possibly. Will you notice? Depends on how many strands get broken.

Best course of action - ask the glass repair companies for their advice -. they are sure to have done some before you!